# Date format in Mongo DB is wrong

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In Database the date format stored is as below. Adding two same fields but values are different.
`packageDeliveredTime : 2020-08-21 2:39:37`
`packageDeliveredTime : 2020-08-21 09:3:45`
Due to the the above format few of the API's and database query's are not filtering the data correctly and like this there is so many records that got stored in the data base.

The above date format needs to get updated as below.
`packageDeliveredTime : 2020-08-21 02:39:37`
`packageDeliveredTime : 2020-08-21 09:03:45`

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects.

In order to convert the strings to date function [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) is not sufficient. You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library to do this:

```
db.collection.find({ packageDeliveredTime: { $exists: true, $type: "string" } }).forEach(function (doc) {
   db.collection.updateOne(
      { _id: doc._id },
      { $set: { packageDeliveredTime: moment(doc.packageDeliveredTime).toDate() } }
   );
})
```